# Is va_start required in variadic arguments for functions?

Tags: c, variadic-functions, variadic-macros

I'm reading the text The Linux Programming Interface and they show this function to handle errors.  In the man pages (`man stdarg`) it says `va_start` must be called first to initialize `ap` for use by `va_arg()` and `va_end`.

So why in this function there is no `va_start`?

```
static void
outputError(Boolean useErr, int err, Boolean flushStdout,
        const char *format, va_list ap) 
{
#define BUF_SIZE 500
    char buf[BUF_SIZE], userMsg[BUF_SIZE], errText[BUF_SIZE];

    vsnprintf(userMsg, BUF_SIZE, format, ap);

    if (useErr)                                                                               
        snprintf(errText, BUF_SIZE, " [%s %s]",
                (err > 0 && err <= MAX_ENAME) ?
                ename[err] : "?UNKNOWN?", strerror(err));
    else
        snprintf(errText, BUF_SIZE, ":");

    snprintf(buf, BUF_SIZE, "ERROR%s %s\n", errText, userMsg);

    if (flushStdout)
        fflush(stdout);       /* Flush any pending stdout */
    fputs(buf, stderr);
    fflush(stderr);           /* In case stderr is not line-buffered */
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`va_list ap` is passed as argument to the function `outputError()`, it must be initialized by `va_start` in the caller of `outputError()` (or caller of caller, etc).

To answer your main question, yes, `va_start` is required, but not necessarily in the current function where `vp_list` is used. The same for `va_end`.

Answer (score 1):

> So why in this function there is no `va_start`?

Here is one of the places that `outputError()` is used:

```
void
errMsg(const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list argList;
    int savedErrno;
    savedErrno = errno;
    /* In case we change it here */
    va_start(argList, format);
    outputError(TRUE, errno, TRUE, format, argList);
    va_end(argList);
    errno = savedErrno;
}
```

I think this answered your question clearly.